# Current QuantLib implementation for Mac OS

Tags: packages, mathlink-or-wstp, finance

Does anyone know of a current [QuantLib](http://www.quantlib.org) implementation that can run on Mathematica version 10.3.0 (or higher) for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)?

About QuantLib:

> The QuantLib project is aimed at providing a comprehensive software
>   framework for quantitative finance. QuantLib is a free/open-source
>   library for modeling, trading, and risk management in real-life.
>
> QuantLib is written in C++ with a clean object model, and is then
>   exported to different languages such as C#, Objective Caml, Java,
>   Perl, Python, GNU R, Ruby, and Scheme.
>
> An AAD-enabled version is also available. The reposit project facilitates deployment of object
>   libraries to end user platforms and is used to generate QuantLibXL, an
>   Excel addin for QuantLib, and QuantLibAddin, QuantLib addins for other
>   platforms such as LibreOffice Calc.
>
> Bindings to other languages and porting to Gnumeric, Matlab/Octave, S-PLUS/R, Mathematica, COM/CORBA/SOAP architectures, FpML, are under consideration.

Certainly recent additions to Mathematica in `Financial Derivative` and `FinancialBond` have added to its functionality, but Mathematica just doesn't have the extensive built-in support for sophisticated quantitative engineering that one can get with something like [MATLAB's Financial Instrument's Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fininst/index.html) (granted its an add-on, but I REALLY wish Wolfram would consider not ceding this professional application to MATLAB).

One does find hints of things...

Thomas Weber has a Mathematica implementation at [Weber and Partner](http://www.weber-und-partner.com/QuantLib/mma/Index.html), but it only appears to run on Windows.

He has a nice [Financial Modeling with Mathematica and QuantLib](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8031/FinancialModelingWithMathematicaAndQuantLib.nb?file_id=7640)  presentation at a Wolfram Technology Conference which just teases Mac users ;-(

Niels Elken Sønderby has a page for a QuantLib Mathematica project  [QuantLibMma](http://www.nielses.dk/quantlib/mma/) but it does not appear to have developed beyond 2003 or so.

J. Robert Buchanan, Department of Mathematics Millersville University (circa 2008) has a presentation entitled [Integrating QuantLib and Mathematica](http://banach.millersville.edu/~bob/presentations/FM2008.pdf) but doesn't go much beyond:

> 1. Create source code for external function (C/C++/FORTRAN/Java).
> 2. Compile source code with an interface “stub” which specifies how
>      Mathematica expressions will be communicated to the external
>      function.
> 3. Load the external routine into a running Mathematica
>      kernel.
> 4. Evaluate the function as if it were a native function.

This might work, but I haven't knocked around with (C/C++/FORTRAN/Java) in over a decade.  I'll try to email him and see if anything developed.

Happy to pursue/try this.  If anyone has experience doing this I'd appreciate hearing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not appear that anyone has developed an open source [QuantLib](http://www.quantlib.org/) implementation that can run on Mathematica 10.3.0 (or higher) for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit).

I have discovered a company that has a Mathematica implementation of comparable (if not better) functionality.  Take a look at [UnRisk](https://www.unrisk.com/index.php/solutions/risk-analysis-and-management).

Note: I have no stake in or association with the company.

I have worked with the trial version (essentially a well formed Mathematica package) and found it thoughtfully conceived.  It has a broad range of solutions for pricing just about any derivative or financial instrument one would encounter in even sophisticate quant shops, investment banks, or hedge funds and seems to make good advantage of Mathematica run efficiencies.

While not inexpensive at something around 4200,00 EURO (roughly $4,800 at this writing), if anyone has more than a hobby interest in this stuff, it seems worthwhile.  It also comes in significantly cheaper than something like the [MATLAB Financial Instrument's Toolbook](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fininst/index.html).